# MySQL - using column from CASE WHEN into WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I want to create a SQL command which will be checking if record exists and:

> 1) if it exists, it will be equal to 1,
>
> 2) if it does not exist, it will be equal to NULL.

And the next step - this value (1 or NULL) I want to use in WHERE clause.

So script should checking if record exist in `table_private`, if yes, it should search by:

```
SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE advert_id = 5795 and img_user_id = 1
```

if not, it should search by:

```
SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE advert_id = 5795 and img_user_id is NULL
```

Here is my sql command:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table_private` WHERE
client_id = 1 AND id = 5795) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS exist_value 
FROM `images` WHERE advert_id = 5795 AND img_user_id = exist_value;
```

But I got:

`Nieznana kolumna 'exist_value' w  where clause`
Why? This column is exist - when I remove this part of command: `AND img_user_id = exist_value`, sql returning correctly this column as resuslt.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot use aliases from select expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: So how I can do it to get result as I want?

Comment: You can replace the reference to the alias with a copy of the entire expression being aliased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Edit: removed stuff no longer applicable after further information gleaned.)*

To specifically show the suggestion in the comments for completeness:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table_private` WHERE
client_id = 1 AND id = 5795) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS exist_value 
FROM `images` 
WHERE advert_id = 5795 
AND img_user_id 
    <=> /* exist_value */ 
      CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                            FROM `table_private` 
                            WHERE client_id = 1 AND id = 5795) 
           THEN NULL 
           ELSE 1 
      END
;
```

Comment: It doesn't help me, because I need to add `is null` instead of `= NULL`. It's very important in my script to set null value, I can't do it only with  = 1.

Comment: Do you mean you need `... img_user_id <=> CASE ...`? _`<=> is null safe equals operator._

Comment: I change my query for: `SELECT * FROM images WHERE advert_id = 5795 AND img_user_id <=> CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_private WHERE id = 5795 AND client_id = 1) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END` but I got no results. When I change this query for: `SELECT * FROM images WHERE advert_id = 5795 AND img_user_id is NULL`, I got five results, so operator `<=>` doesn't help me.

Comment: To be sure, what does `SELECT * FROM table_private WHERE id = 5795 AND client_id = 1` return?

Comment: I tried with your query and it's the same situation. 0 results, but when I try with: `SELECT * FROM images WHERE advert_id = 5795 AND img_user_id is NULL` I got 5 results.

Comment: I understand that, what do these two queries result in? `SELECT * FROM table_private WHERE id = 5795 AND client_id = 1` and `SELECT * FROM images WHERE advert_id = 5795 AND img_user_id = 1` If the first returns anything, and the second nothing; your query should return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HAVING` to filter based on a calculated value in the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT *, 
        CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * 
                FROM `table_private` 
                WHERE client_id = 1 AND id = 5795) 
             THEN NULL 
             ELSE 1 
        END AS exist_value 
FROM `images` WHERE advert_id = 5795
HAVING img_user_id <=> exist_value;
```

[`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) is the null-safe equality operator, it allows comparison with `NULL`.

Comment: ye, now I checked that and `= NULL` is bad idea because I got 0 results. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Could you edit the question and explain what the whole query is supposed to do? Show some sample data and the desired result. Is there any relationship between `images` and `table_private`?

Comment: Table `images` magazine all images from my server. If image has NULL value as `img_user_id` -> this is default image (common from the server, user never edit/change that image). If record exist in `table_private` then  script should always getting images where img_user_id = USER_ID because this user saved in past some images so he doesn't use default (NULL) images, but their (= 1).

Comment: So if record exist in `table_private`, script should getting data from: `... img_user_id = 1` but when record doesn't exist in `table_private`, script should getting data from `img_user_id is NULL`

Comment: It looks like just using the `<=>` operator should do it. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the data in a outer query like

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table_private` WHERE
client_id = 1 AND id = 5795) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS exist_value 
FROM `images` ) xxx
WHERE advert_id = 5795 
AND img_user_id = exist_value;
```

Comment: When NOT EXISTS() is true, then column `exist_value` = NULL. Then in select statement is: `AND img_user_id = NULL;` but it could be: `AND img_user_id is NULL`